# I want to create the partitions in filesystem. is that possible?

Tags: 10.04, disk

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 recently. I mean today! And I want my FileSystem (80GB) to be divided into three part just like windows do! Is that possible? If yes Please help me!

Comment: Boot Ubuntu Liveusb>Open gparted>create partitions>done.

Comment: Be sure you understand how Ubuntu refers to partitions before you go re-sizing them. Also know that you can only have 4 primary partitions. To have more then 4 partitions, you then need to use an extended partition (with logical partitions inside). If you did not understand what I just said see : http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual Last I suggest you consider making a /home partition.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to partition your hard disk in three partitions. You will need to boot using ubuntu live cd and run Gparted from there. You can find it at System->Administration->Gparted. Using it you can resize your current partition and then create two new partitions in the space that frees up.

But you should understand that it wont be like Windows. Windows has separate directory trees for each partition but Linux/Ubuntu has one directory tree and your new partition will still be part of that. You may not notice it as long as you are using GUI as you will get drive icons on the desktop and in Places menu but if you use command line then you should understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. But you need a live-cd for this. Login using live-cd then do the rest of the work.
http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions
OR
You can also resize partition using gparted.

Generally Data will not loss but backup your files[home,Desktop, etc which are in filesystem] for security.

After resize the partition update your grub.
http://shantanucse.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-recover-ubuntu-904-or-higher.html

Comment: Can you include the details from the linked articles?